# TableViewController not displaying full content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The header label of the tableViewCell is always cut out and detailText is only partially shown when the detailText is greater than 3 lines. I've set the `rowHeight` and `estimatedRowHeight`but the outcome remains the same.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
      //self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100

    }
```

How `TableViewController` Should look 
[image]

Outcome
[image]

Comment: do you have this function `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` ?

Answer (score 0):

navigation bar is overlap on Tableview . check it

and set

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100;
```

not

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Comment: I've tried this, outcome remained the same. Issue seems to only exits on simulator which is strange (view shows correctly on device)